# Can I create a conditional find & replace with a regular expression?

Tags: regex, nginx

I am using trying to a NginX substitution filter which allows the use of regular expressions. I can get it working in a basic manner, i.e. replacing `phone` with `telephone`, but I can't seem to get it to conditionally replace a string of text.

Here is a check of XML for examination:

```
eat apples cantaloupe bananas often
```

I would like to perform the following set of rules:

1. Look for a string starting with `eat` and ending with `often`
2. If the string contains `bananas` then replace `bananas` with `and especially bananas`
3. If the string does not contain bananas do not do anything to the string

I know that I can use something like this to make parts of the string available:

```
/(eat.*)(bananas)?(.*often)/
```

I could use the following rule to do the replacement assuming `bananas` is present:

```
   $1 and especially $2 $3
```

But this will give an odd result if `bananas` is not present:

input

```
eat apples cantaloupe often
```

output:

```
eat apples cantaloupe and especially often
```

Do I need a look ahead operator? I've read [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) but I'm still having trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a look ahead:

```
/(?=.*eat.*bananas.*often) bananas/
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative without lookahead:

```
Raw Match Pattern:
^eat(.*)(bananas)(.*)often$

Raw Replace Pattern:
eat \1 and especially \2 often

$sourcestring before replacement:
do not eat bananas often
eat apples cantaloupe often
eat apples cantaloupe bananas often

$sourcestring after replacement:   
do not eat bananas often
eat apples cantaloupe often
eat apples cantaloupe and especially bananas often
```